# How to change background image in django web app using the admin interface?

Tags: python, html, django, web-development-server

I want to change the background of the home page in my web app but using the admin interface. I made a model specific for the backgrounds of each section used in the home page.

this was my first approach, which is editing the save function and give the image name the id name as 1.jpg then reffering to 1.jpg in my html file

Here is the my ImageHome model for the images in the background:

```
def save_home_image(instance, filename):
    upload_to = 'Images/'
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    # get filename
    if instance.name:
        filename = 'Home_Pictures/{}.{}'.format(instance.name, ext)
    return os.path.join(upload_to, filename)

def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return os.path.join('Images', 'Home_Pictures', f'{instance.name}.{ext}')

class ImageHome(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image_home = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=custom_upload_to,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Home Image',
        null=True,
        max_length=500
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if an image with the same name exists
        try:
            existing_image = ImageHome.objects.get(name=self.name)
            
            # Delete the existing image
            if existing_image.image_home:
                existing_image.image_home.delete()

        except ImageHome.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        # Call the original save method to save the new image
        super(ImageHome, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here is the code in my html file:

```
<section 
    data-image-width="1980" data-image-height="1320" style="background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 49, 51, 0.5), rgba(41, 49, 51, 0.5)), 
    
    url('/media/Images/Home_Pictures/1.jpg')
    
    ; background-position: 50% 50%;">
```

my second approach I didn't add any save function in the model
so the code was like this:

```
def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return os.path.join('Images', 'Home_Pictures', f'{instance.name}.{ext}')

class ImageHome(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    image_home = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=custom_upload_to,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Home Image',
        null=True,
        max_length=500
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

but i added a new view in the views.py

```
def Image_nb_4(request):
    # Retrieve the ImageHome object with ID 4
    image = ImageHome.objects.get(id=4)
    
    context = {
        'image4': image,
    }

    return render(request, 'curriculum/Home.html', context)
```

then referred it in home.html

```
<section 
    data-image-width="1980" data-image-height="1320" style="background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(41, 49, 51, 0.5), rgba(41, 49, 51, 0.5)), 
    
    url('{{ image4.image_home.url }}')
    
    ; background-position: 50% 50%;">
```

still didnt work

Comment: why is that not working and when you use inspect odes it shows the URL of the image ?

Comment: ali, no it's not showing. it's driving me crazy

Comment: can you please show me the inspect of this   `<section>` tag  from your browser please ? i want to know how the django templates are interpreting it